# How to add extra column to protractor-html-screenshot-reporter like duration for each "it" block

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to add an extra column to the HTML report. Like duration of each "it" block. I tried this inside **jsonparser.js** file.

```
phssr.makeHTMLPage = function(tableHtml, reporterOptions){
    var styleTag = phssr.makeHardCodedStyleTag(reporterOptions);
    var scrpTag = phssr.makeScriptTag();

    var staticHTMLContentprefix = "<html><head><meta charset='utf-8'/>";

    //Add title if it was in config setup
    if (typeof (reporterOptions.docTitle) !== 'undefined' && _.isString(reporterOptions.docTitle) ){
        staticHTMLContentprefix += "<title>" + reporterOptions.docTitle + "</title>";
    } else {
        staticHTMLContentprefix += "<title></title>";
    }

    staticHTMLContentprefix +=  styleTag + scrpTag + " </head><body>";
    staticHTMLContentprefix +=  "<h1>" + reporterOptions.docHeader + "</h1><table class='header'>";
    staticHTMLContentprefix +=  "<tr><th class='desc-col'>Description</th><th class='status-col'>Passed</th>";
    staticHTMLContentprefix +=  "<th class='browser-col'>Browser</th>";
    staticHTMLContentprefix +=  "<th class='os-col'>OS</th><th class='msg-col'>Message</th>";
    staticHTMLContentprefix +=  "<th class='msg-col'>Duration</th>";
    staticHTMLContentprefix +=  "<th class='img-col'>Screenshot</th></tr></table>";

    var staticHTMLContentpostfix = "</body></html>";
    var htmlComplete = staticHTMLContentprefix + tableHtml + staticHTMLContentpostfix;

    return htmlComplete;
}

phssr.getTimestamp = function (date) {
            function pad(n) { return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n; }
            var currentDate = date !== undefined ? date : new Date(),
                month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1,
                day = currentDate.getDate();
            return (currentDate.getFullYear() + "-" + pad(month) + "-" + pad(day) + " " + pad(currentDate.getHours()) + ":" + pad(currentDate.getMinutes()) + ":" + pad(currentDate.getSeconds()));
}

var sTime = new Date();
var startTime = phssr.getTimestamp(sTime);
console.log("sTime***********************",startTime);

var passCount=0, failCount=0, loopCount=0;
function generateHTML(data){
    var eTime = new Date();
    var endTime = phssr.getTimestamp(eTime);
    console.log("eTime***********************",endTime);
    var diffTime = (eTime-sTime)/1000;

    console.log("dTime***********************",diffTime);

    data.passed? passCount++: failCount++;
    var str = '<table><tr>';
    str +=  '<td class="desc-col">' + data.desc + '</td>';
    var bgColor = data.passed? 'green': 'red';
    str +=  '<td class="status-col" style="color:#fff;background-color: '+ bgColor+'">' + data.passed + '</td>';
    str +=  '<td class="browser-col">' + data.browser.name+ ':' +data.browser.version + '</td>';
    str +=  '<td class="os-col">' + data.os + '</td>';
    var stackTraceInfo = data.passed? '': '<br/><a onclick="showTrace(event)" href="#trace-modal'+loopCount+'">View Stack Trace Info</a><br/> <div id="#trace-modal'+loopCount+'" class="traceinfo"><div><a href="#close" onclick="closeTraceModal(event)" title="Close" class="close">X</a>' + data.trace + '</div></div>';

    str +=  '<td class="msg-col">' + data.message+ stackTraceInfo+ '</td>';
    str +=  '<td class="msg-col">' + diffTime + '</td>';

    if(!(reporterOptions.takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs && data.passed)) {
        str +=  '<td class="img-col"><a href="#" onclick="openModal(\'' + path.basename(data.screenShotFile)+ '\')">View </a></td>';
    }
    else{
        str +=  '<td class="img-col"></td>';
    }

    str += '</tr></table>';
    loopCount++;
    return str;

}
```

I can see the extra column in the report. The problem was it is not showing the correct time. In the console it is printing like this

```
sTime*********************** 2015-08-28 13:26:44
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
.eTime*********************** 2015-08-28 13:26:48
dTime*********************** 3.312
.eTime*********************** 2015-08-28 13:26:52
dTime*********************** 7.984
eTime*********************** 2015-08-28 13:26:52
dTime*********************** 7.984
.

Finished in 12.123 seconds
3 tests, 3 assertions, 0 failures

eTime*********************** 2015-08-28 13:26:57
dTime*********************** 12.325
eTime*********************** 2015-08-28 13:26:57
dTime*********************** 12.325
eTime*********************** 2015-08-28 13:26:57
dTime*********************** 12.325
```

here, I don't know why it is executing two times. In the report it is showing `12.325` for all blocks. I don't know where I am doing wrong. please help me.

**Tests:**

```
describe('Title', function() {
           it('TESTCASE-1 : Should have a title', function() {
             expect(browser.getTitle()).toContain('Test');
           });

             it('TESTCASE-2 : Should accept a valid email address and password', function() {

              element(by.id('email')).sendKeys('*********');
              element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('*********');
              element(by.css('.btn')).click();         
              expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('*********/app/#/home');
              });

         it('TESTCASE-4: Dashboard Selection.....', function(){ 
             var menubutton = element.all(by.css('.btn')).get(0);
             menubutton.click();
             expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('*************************/students/1');
         });
    });
```

Comment: I feel that your `jsonparser` file is still waiting for few promises to resolve even after your test case is completed, so it prints those lines even after completion. How are you using this function in your tests?